# Как сделать множественный insert одной записью?

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

Есть такой запрос:

```
self.cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO items (res_id, log_id, link, title, content, n_date, nd_date, s_date, not_date)
                       VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)''',
                       ( res_id,
                         log_id,
                         str(resource_link),
                         str(item_title),
                         str(item_content),
                         str(n_date),
                         nd_date,
                         s_date,
                         not_date
                       )
                                )
```

Как можно сделать чтобы этот запрос добавлял новости не по одной новости за раз,а за один раз 100 новостей?

Я смотрел такой пример множественного `insert` в интернете:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable
  ( Column1, Column2, Column3 )
VALUES
  ('John', 123, 'Lloyds Office'), 
  ('Jane', 124, 'Lloyds Office'), 
  ('Billy', 125, 'London Office'),
  ('Miranda', 126, 'Bristol Office');
```

Но в этом случае надо указать `VALUES` столько раз,сколько надо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Воспользуйтесь “executemany()”](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-executemany.html):

```
sql = '''
INSERT INTO MyTable
  ( Column1, Column2, Column3 )
VALUES
  (%s, %s, %s)
'''

records = [
  ('John', 123, 'Lloyds Office'), 
  ('Jane', 124, 'Lloyds Office'), 
  ('Billy', 125, 'London Office'),
  ('Miranda', 126, 'Bristol Office')]

cursor.executemany(sql, records)
```

Comment: В моем вопросе,пример был похожий.Но меня интересует вопрос,вот мне надо 100 записей за один раз.Тогда в я должен же  VALUES  100 раз указать ?

Comment: В ответе указан __готовый__ пример, который за раз вставит 4 записи. Если в records будет 100 записей - вставит 100. sql при этом остаётся неизменным

Comment: Окей,благодарю вас за ответ.